# Basics of autolayout in Xcode 6

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

Here's my question:

- In Xcode 6 Beta 4, I've created a single-view iOS 8 application.
- In StoryBoard, I've dragged a `UITextView` object onto it.

Without writing any code (i.e. using built-in auto sizing and constraints), here's my goal:

**Have this `UITextView`'s width be *almost* the width of the screen width, regardless of that screen's width. But have 20 pixels of padding on the left and right**.

Help! Is this even possible? Surely it is???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the 4 constraints shown in the screenshot.

[image]

You are pinning the textview to be 0 points from the top and bottom as well as 20 points from the left (leading) and right (trailing) space.

Comment: Perfect Chris. Thanks so much—I've confirmed this is working on my end too. I'm realizing my problem is so perplexing because I'm trying to have this `UITextView` inside a `UIScrollView`. That's the part that's got me completely stumped for hours. Any tips?

Comment: So, that's going to be a bit trickier from my experience. A scrollview needs a content size. Your text view will manage it's content size on it's own. But you need to manage the content size of your scroll view manually. I would install width and height constraints on the text view so that Xcode doesn't complain about the scroll view's content size being ambiguous. Then I would create outlets for those constraints and update them appropriately for the view's size... Not clean but I've always found it to be a bear working with scroll views inside of scroll views (UITextView is a scrollview).

Comment: Hmm okay. Then how about just a `UILabel` inside of a `UISCrollView`? I'm struggling with getting even something like that working in Xcode 6. 

Almost feels like an Xcode bug; if I set the `UIScrollView`'s width to equal the width of the superview, and then set the width of the `UILabel` to either the width of the superview or the width of the `UIScrollView`, it doesn't work. The `UILabel` is way too far to the right because it incorrectly thinks my screen width is much greater than 320. So weird...